# I cannot get the jQuery inputmask plugin to work

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-inputmask

I want to have a mask on my input box that only accepts currency.

jQuery has a plugin for that; https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask

However I can't get to work.

What am I missing from this code?

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>

<h2>Index</h2>
<input class="" style="text-align: right;" data-inputmask="'alias': 'numeric', 'groupSeparator': ',', 'autoGroup': true, 'digits': 2, 'digitsOptional': false, 'prefix': '£ ', 'placeholder': '0'"/>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.inputmask/jquery.inputmask-3.0.57.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.inputmask/jquery.inputmask.numeric.extensions-3.0.57.js")"></script>
```

Comment: you need to call `$(":input").inputmask();` on dom ready

Comment: That looks about right to me, although .inputmask() is not recognised

Comment: then the inclusion of inputmask library is not proper

Comment: You have given the correct answer. For some reason it does not work on my test page, but it does in my main application. So if you give comments as your answer I will tick you.

Comment: Make sure you call `$(":input").inputmask()` after you load the inputmask scripts.